# python3.9.12 windows unable find tflite_runtime.interpreter

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, tflite

I try pip install tflite_runtime.
But it shows
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite_runtime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tflite_runtime

Comment: [TensorFlow Lite is a mobile library for deploying models on mobile, microcontrollers and other edge devices.](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/#files yes, there is no Win build. Get your tensorflow, it has tflite interpreter in package.

Answer (score 0):

tflite-runtime package has no prebuilt wheels for windows on pypi for versions 2.5.0+.

It leaves you with few possible solutions:

1. Use available prebuilt tflite-runtime 2.5.0 package for windows (which is quite old)
2. Build version you need from source (guide: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/pip_package/README.md, TF team answer on similar question: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-to-install-tflite-runtime-in-windows-machine/11427)
3. Use full tensorflow package which has tf.lite.Interpreter
4. Search somewhere for pre-built tflite-runtime package for windows (I haven't found any)